# Send raw bitcoin transaction with js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, blockchain

I'm trying to make a little web app (just for learning purposes), where I can push on a button, and it will send some bitcoin from (my own) bitcoin wallet A to bitcoin wallet B. I've managed to learn some stuff about bitcoin, the blockchain, and figured out how to make a raw bitcoin transaction like so:

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('****************************');
var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder();

tx.addInput('****************************', 0);
tx.addOutput('****************************', 546);
tx.sign(0, keyPair);

console.log(tx.build().toHex());
generatedhash = tx.build().toHex();
```

If I take the generatedhash to a website like https://blockr.io/tx/push it will succesfully do the bitcoin transaction, but I'd like to know if its possible to automate pushing the raw transaction using js as well? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: You can do a post request with axios to push it through: https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/bcy/test/txs/push once you've generated the raw transaction.

Comment: @Pazzle Could you answer your own Question with a bit more informations? That would be really nice :) thx

Answer (score 0):

first of i am not affiliated but for lack of a easier tool,
using [bitcore explorer](https://bitcore.io/api/explorers/):

> **Insight** is a simple agent to perform queries to an Insight blockchain
>   explorer. The default servers are https://insight.bitpay.com and
>   https://test-insight.bitpay.com, hosted by BitPay Inc. You can (and we
>   strongly suggest you do) run your own insight server. For more
>   information, head to https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api

```
var Insight = require('bitcore-explorers').Insight;
var insight = new Insight();
insight.broadcast(tx, function(err, returnedTxId) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle errors...
  } else {
    // Mark the transaction as broadcasted
  }
});
```